# How calculate data in every month in range time and add to one List if know time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datetime, time

I have a start time: startTime: 09-2017 and the end time is endTime: 05-2018. I want to calculate the amount of data each month then add up to calculate the data in the period from start to finish. For example, start time is 09-2017 and ends on 5-2018. In the 8-month period, I want to calculate the data for each month and then add up to calculate the all-time period. I used the for loop for the ending time minus one month.The loop will stop if month of endTime equal monthOfStartTime. I save the data to an arrayList and after a month I will add it back. Below is my code:

startTime: 09-2017;
endTime: 05-2018;

```
@Autowired
private StudentDao studentDao;
//total students in 8 month
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();


//caculator data in everyMonth
 for (int i = dateTimeNow.getMonthOfYear(); i >= 0; i--) {
    //break if equal startTime.
    LocalDateTime startTimeCaculator = endTime.getMonthOfYear().minusMonths(i-1);
    List<Student> studentOnMonth =
     studentDao.getDataEveryMonth(startTimeCaculator,endTime);
    students.addAll(studentOnMonth);
   }
```

I have two question. What is the condition for a loop to stop when I count the start date? Secondly, if I use the i = endTime.getMonthOfYear variable, the loop will count from the end of month to zero, and will not count over the years. Time to finish 5-2018, the loop will run 5 times and not count through the months of 2017. Please help.

Comment: It doesn’t answer your question in itself, but the `YearMonth` class seems right for representing start and end and controlling your loop.

Comment: Thank you. And second question?  has no loop to repeat the loop without loop 0. That means if me starting from 5-2018 and want to repeat to the 10-2017 and stop me may be use YearMonth as you says than. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d control the loop like this:

```
    YearMonth endMonth = YearMonth.of(2018, Month.MAY);
    YearMonth startMonth = YearMonth.of(2017, Month.SEPTEMBER);
    for (YearMonth m = endMonth; m.isAfter(startMonth); m = m.minusMonths(1)) {
        LocalDateTime monthStart = m.atDay(1).atStartOfDay();
        LocalDateTime monthEnd = m.plusMonths(1).atDay(1).atStartOfDay();

        System.out.println("Month from " + monthStart + " inclusive to " + monthEnd + " exclusive");
    }
```

As the snippet stands here it outputs:

```
Month from 2018-05-01T00:00 inclusive to 2018-06-01T00:00 exclusive
Month from 2018-04-01T00:00 inclusive to 2018-05-01T00:00 exclusive
Month from 2018-03-01T00:00 inclusive to 2018-04-01T00:00 exclusive
Month from 2018-02-01T00:00 inclusive to 2018-03-01T00:00 exclusive
Month from 2018-01-01T00:00 inclusive to 2018-02-01T00:00 exclusive
Month from 2017-12-01T00:00 inclusive to 2018-01-01T00:00 exclusive
Month from 2017-11-01T00:00 inclusive to 2017-12-01T00:00 exclusive
Month from 2017-10-01T00:00 inclusive to 2017-11-01T00:00 exclusive
```

If it wasn’t exactly what you wanted, please adjust.

You may also want to modify your student DAO to accept a `YearMonth` argument. This would depend on the flexibility you want: passing two datetime instances allows for shorter or longer periods than one month so gives greater flexibility.

Edit: If you want `startMonth` to be included, use “not before” to mean on or after, for example:

```
    YearMonth endMonth = YearMonth.of(2017, Month.OCTOBER);
    YearMonth startMonth = YearMonth.of(2017, Month.SEPTEMBER);
    for (YearMonth m = endMonth; ! m.isBefore(startMonth); m = m.minusMonths(1)) {
        LocalDateTime monthStart = m.atDay(1).atStartOfDay();
        LocalDateTime monthEnd = m.plusMonths(1).atDay(1).atStartOfDay();

        System.out.println("Month from " + monthStart + " inclusive to " + monthEnd + " exclusive");
    }
```

Output:

```
Month from 2017-10-01T00:00 inclusive to 2017-11-01T00:00 exclusive
Month from 2017-09-01T00:00 inclusive to 2017-10-01T00:00 exclusive
```

Comment: Thank you. But when i used it it exceed toTime. How to fix it equal toTime. I want data low to toTime."Month from 2018-05-01T00:00 inclusive to 2018-06-01T00:00 exclusive" it exceed toTime.

Comment: And you can't caculator data from 09-2017 -> 10-2017

Comment: ! m.isBefore(startMonth) . It work. Thank you very much ^^.

Answer (score 1):

You can use isAfter() function like this:

```
LocalDateTime endTime= ....; // 05-2018
LocalDateTime startTime= ....; // 09-2017
while(endTime.isAfter(startTime)){
   endtime = endTime.minusMonths(1);
   ....
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But if i used it loop count to startTime and break ? That means if me starting from 5-2018 and want to repeat to the 10-2017 it stop in 10-2017 ??

Comment: There is no direct way to do that, but if you want to get the number of months between to dates, use: startTime.until(endTime, ChronoUnit.MONTHS); and you can make your loop. I hope that help